# auto show vote count on homepage

Tags: feature-request, voting, votes

Is there any way to automatically show the vote count ex. 5 up votes and 3 down votes = 2 up votes when viewing the list of questions on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)?

Comment: Any specific reason?

Comment: Yea, I like looking at questions that have many up and down votes.  I like controversy.

Comment: You might want to take a look at "Hot" questions: [How are "Hot" Questions Selected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected)

Comment: Any solution for this problem will require 1k rep, since users below 1k can't even see split vote counts for individual posts. Also, if you like controversy, check out my [controversy/insightfulness badge request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101567/meta-sites-should-have-a-badge-for-insightfulness-controversy), which is itself at +28/-11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ones you refer to are available [at this Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/87/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site), other than that query it isn't really useful to show this for posts on the frontpage given that the low amount of votes would not show controversy.

It can be done using an user script, but I don't think that it's allowed to query the votes for each question.